# How can I obtain execution trace of a C# application at statement level?

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-engineering, managed, cil

This is my problem. I have an .exe file written in C#. I do not have access to the original source code or pdb file.

I want to obtain a trace of what is being executed inside a method at statement level. I am aware that C# source gets converted to CIL and is further compiled at runtime.

I have found .NET profilers which offer execution trace composed of methods, return values and parameter values. Some tools that I found are: [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html), [redgate ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), [telerik justTrace](http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx), [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/index.html).

I would like to get a trace of CIL commands equivalent for each statement.
I know that there can be further compiler optimizations which can modify the CIL code or different type of compiling managed code ([short info](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-net-just-in-time-compilation)).

One approach to automatically add logging is [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) but again offers a too high-level view for my case.

As far as I can understand CLRProfiler offers API methods for method entry and exit points and so on. There are no APIs to trace the executed statements.

The idea that I have so far is to manually write a code injector at CIL level as described here ([part-1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/445858/Tracing-with-Code-Injection) and [part-2](http://girishjjain.com/blog/post/Tracing-with-Code-Injection-Part-II.aspx)) which for each statement will print the equivalent CIL code.

Has anyone a better idea or is aware of any similar tool?
For binary assemblies, [Intel Pin](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/index.html) can provide a similar functionality.

**Update**

I do not want to simply read the source code, I want to see what is executed.
I am well aware of all decompilers.
I am doing this in the context of obfuscation and deobfuscation.
For example, if I have a method which computes a fibonnacci number and on that it is applied control flow obfuscation and other obfuscation methods, simply reading the source code is not enough. I want to see how that method is executed.

I need **dynamic tracing**.

Comment: Why not use a decompiler?

Comment: this postsharp things look intersting

Comment: @Nasreddine please read the updated question. thanks for asking

Comment: dotPeek lets you export a pdb file, which you should be able to use to step through execution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to reverse engineer, you'd have better luck with something like [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), which will let you convert the IL into human-readable C#.

If the executable has been obfuscated, then profiling and decompiling aren't going to help you much anyways.

Answer (score 1):

For your's you simply have to decompile the application [using some decompiler like telerik, ILOgic, dotpeek e.t.c] then put some tracing into the methods you want's to check. [may be use log4net or simple buliltin trace].
Have done these type of things lot of time

Answer (score 0):

ILDASM.exe can provide you much of what you are looking for. It's packaged with VS.

Comment: @cipri.l in response to your update, i'm not sure about exe but i'm sure about dll dynamic tracing, you can do it using pdb file. You might want to look into pdb.

Comment: Imra thanks for your input. I do not have the pdb file.

Comment: How exactly is ILDasm going to help here? It just gives you the raw IL, it doesn't tell you what's executed at runtime.

Comment: @svick code will not get executed from space, it'd be from that IL. And, IL is going to provide whole code statement by statement even if code is obfuscated.I It'd tell each control structure in very detail, what statements  a function is executing at very lower level (plz see updated question). No tool is going to give you that much detail.